# My mobile screen touches itself repeatedly(Ghost Touches)?

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, touch

I have Swipe Elite Note android mobile phone.
My mobile screen touches itself repeatedly. I tink it might be a hardware issue.
However, it is working well today!
How can I confirm if it was an hardware issue or a software problem?

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode... Does the problem persist? If yes, probably hardware, if no, factory reset and try again.

Comment: Likely to be hardware but to confirm you could see if this behaviour persists in safe mode - of it doesn't, it *may* point to software ( you would need to check multiple times given that the problem seems random)

Comment: @beeshyams Is there any app using which I can disable that part of my mobile screen touch?

Comment: No but they're are questions here on how to that - search for them for possible ways